# Flatten (kind of) JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following array:

```
var data = {
    menu: [{
        name: 'Step 1',
        sub: [{
            name: 'Step 1 sub A',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Step 1 sub B',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Step 1 sub C',
            sub: [{
                name: 'Step 1 sub C sub A',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Step 1 sub C sub B',
                sub: [{
                    name: 'Step 1 sub C sub B sub A',
                    sub: null
                }, {
                    name: 'Step 1 sub C sub B sub B',
                    sub: null
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Step 2',
        sub: [{
            name: 'Step 2 sub A',
            sub: null
        }, {
            name: 'Step 2 sub B',
            sub: [{
                name: 'Step 2 sub B sub A',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Step 2 sub B sub B',
                sub: null
            }, {
                name: 'Step 2 sub B sub C',
                sub: null
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Step 2 sub B',
            sub: null
        }]
    }]
};
```

What I want to return is e.g.

```
Step 1
Step 1 > Step 1 sub A
Step 1 > Step 1 sub B
Step 1 > Step 1 sub C
Step 1 > Step 1 sub C > Step 1 sub C sub A
Step 1 > Step 1 sub C > Step 1 sub C sub B
etc. etc.
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
var $menu = $("#menu");

var getMenuItem = function (data) {

    var item = data.name; // start

    if (data.sub) { // if we have subs concat them
        var subList = '';
        $.each(data.sub, function () {
            subList =+ getMenuItem(this) + ' > ';
        });
        item = item + ' > ' + subList;
    }
    return item; // now return it
};

$.each(data.menu, function () {
    $menu.append(
        getMenuItem(this) + '<br />'
    );
});
```

But all this returns is:

```
Step 1 > NaN > 
Step 2 > NaN >
```

How should I approach this?

[Here's a fiddle to show the code](http://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/akesz08d/1/)

Comment: That's not JSON.  That's just straight up JavaScript Object. JavaScript Object **Notation** (JSON) is a string based format following particular patterns and practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple recursive function. You need to first create the `li` for the current level, then check for `sub` items and then recurse through those, appending as you go. Try this:

```
function menuFromObject(prev, m) {  
    $.each(m, function(i, menu) {
        var itemName = prev + (prev.length ? ' > ' : '') + menu.name;
        $('#menu').append('<li>' + itemName + '</li>');        
        if (menu.sub && menu.sub.length) 
            menuFromObject(itemName, menu.sub);
    });
}

menuFromObject('', data.menu);
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/akesz08d/5/)

Comment: Many thanks, I haven't done a lot with recursive functions so good to learn - is it possible to stop each last child having `>` as per OP?

Comment: There is indeed with a small logic tweak, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/akesz08d/5/. I updated the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach is definitely the best option here. The following is a bit specific to your use case, but will work just fine.

```
function flatten(prefix, data) {
  for(var attr in data) {
    var n = data.name ? data.name + ' > ' : '';
    if(typeof data === 'object') flatten(prefix + n, data[attr])
    else console.log(prefix + n)
  }
}

// Hacky way is just to feed it a blank string to start
flatten('', data)
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akesz08d/2/) that presents the concept. Clearly it can be improved and customized, but it's a very succinct way of removing the dimension from data like that.

Comment: Thanks, it's close but everything happens 6 times, which would increase to the number of menu items if the menu was bigger

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive function that does what I think you need.  Note that I broke out the first layer to avoid the following:

> Step 1 > Step 1 sub C > Step 1 sub C sub B > Step 1 sub C sub B sub B **> Step 2**

Demo:

```js
var data = {
  menu: [{
    name: 'Step 1',
    sub: [{
      name: 'Step 1 sub A',
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: 'Step 1 sub B',
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: 'Step 1 sub C',
      sub: [{
        name: 'Step 1 sub C sub A',
        sub: null
      }, {
        name: 'Step 1 sub C sub B',
        sub: [{
          name: 'Step 1 sub C sub B sub A',
          sub: null
        }, {
          name: 'Step 1 sub C sub B sub B',
          sub: null
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Step 2',
    sub: [{
      name: 'Step 2 sub A',
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: 'Step 2 sub B',
      sub: [{
        name: 'Step 2 sub B sub A',
        sub: null
      }, {
        name: 'Step 2 sub B sub B',
        sub: null
      }, {
        name: 'Step 2 sub B sub C',
        sub: null
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Step 2 sub B',
      sub: null
    }]
  }]
};

var name = '';
var el = document.querySelector('pre');

function output(s){
  //console.log(s);
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
  el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}

function flatten(menu){
  for(var i = 0, len = menu.length; i < len; i++) {
    var result = (name += ' > ' + menu[i].name);
    output(result);
    if(menu[i].sub)
      flatten(menu[i].sub);
    else 
      name = name.replace(/[\s>]+[^>]+?$/, '');
  }
}
for(var i = 0, len = data.menu.length; i < len; i++) {
  name = data.menu[i].name;
  output(name);
  flatten(data.menu[i].sub);
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```